# Precompiling SCSS: variable is undefined (Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

### The scenario

In **/products.css.scss**:

```
@import 'partials/colors';
@import 'partials/boxes';

#wrapper {}
```

In **/partials/_colors.css.scss**:

```
$light-gray: #ccc;
```

In **/partials/_boxes.css.scss**:

```
#box-light-gray {
  background-color: $light-gray;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

### The problem

It happens on `rake assets:precompile`, in `production` environment:

> Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined variable: "$light-gray".
>     (in /partials/_boxes.css.scss:2)

### My thoughts

The file **/partials/_boxes.css.scss** doesn't have the variable `$light-gray` by itself – and here I have to agree with `rake assets:precompile`. The point is: how do I do to make `rake` recognize the injection of `$light-gray` into **/partials/_boxes.css.scss**?

I think `rake` is not matching the points of the puzzle because it doesn't know how SCSS works. I feel I'm missing something related to SCSS in couple with `rake`.

Comment: How about importing colors into boxes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a tricky problem with the current version of Sprockets and sass-rails.  You would think that the `*= require` lines in your `application.css` file would load the variables in order so that they would be available to all scss files, but it does not.  Here is what the [asset pipeline Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives) says about it:

> If you want to use multiple Sass files, you should generally use the
>   Sass @import rule instead of these Sprockets directives. Using
>   Sprockets directives all Sass files exist within their own scope,
>   making variables or mixins only available within the document they
>   were defined in. You can do file globbing as well using @import "*",
>   and @import "**/*" to add the whole tree equivalent to how
>   require_tree works. Check the sass-rails documentation for more info
>   and important caveats.

In other words, you have a two choices:

- `@import` your variables in each file as you need them
- Use `@import` in your `application.css.scss` file instead of `*= require`

If you go with the first option, just drop in `@import 'partials/colors';` to the top of `_boxes.css.scss`.

With the second option, you just need to `@import` your stylesheets in your `application.css.scss` once (in the proper order), then your variables in mixins will be available to all stylesheets.  You're still using the asset pipeline here so precompilation will still work fine, but you're letting `sass-rails` work its sass magic.  Your `application.css.scss` would look something like this:

```
@import 'partials/colors';
@import 'partials/*';
@import '*';
```

Be warned though, there is currently a [bug](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/issues/185) with sass-rails.  If you have `.erb` stylesheets, sass-rails won't be able to import them by wildcard if they're in a seperate folder.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, but how do I precompile things without sprockets? I want something minified and managable – I think I just can't drop out sprockets.

Comment: Sorry, I guess my wording was unclear.  I'll update my answer. You're not getting rid of sprockets, you're just not using it's `*=require` directives.  Rails will still use sprockets to precompile your stylesheets.  Using `@import` instead of `*=require` makes all the sass mixins and variables filter down to your other stylesheets at the time of precompilation.  I linked to the rails guide section that talks about this, it might explain it better than I.  I've also found the sass-rails github page helpful. https://github.com/rails/sass-rails

Comment: "This is a tricky problem with the current version of Sprockets and sass-rails."  No this is a Major Bug in the way Sprockets works.  It should load the files in the order you specify.  "Using Sprockets directives all Sass files exist within their own scope..."  which is wrong - the point in including them is so that they are available to all files which load next in order.

Answer (score 2):

Without modifying your scss, I think your best option is to put `@import 'partials/colors';` in your `_boxes.css.scss` file also.  The biggest drawback with `@import` is that it includes an additional http request, however since you are precompiling your assests I'm not entirely sure that is still an issue.

Potential refactoring option:

`_colors.css.scss`

```
$light-gray: #ccc;
```

`_box-sizes.css.scss`

```
.small-box{
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
}
```

`products.css.scss`

```
@import 'partials/colors';
@import 'partials/box-sizes';

.small-light-grey-box{
    @extend .small-box
    background-color: $light-gray;
}
```

Again, this is just an example.  There are countless ways you could refactor your scss and html to get the desired outcome.

Comment: So, should I place `@import 'partials/colors';` each time I want to use the colors? Is this redundancy, isn't it?

Comment: I'd say so.  But your scss files are structured so that one file has colors, and if you want to use those colors you need to import them in with the rules that uses them, I don't know of anyway around that.  For what it's worth, I think `@import 'partials/colors'` in the scss files in which you need those defined colors is a lot more DRY than putting `$light-gray: #ccc; ... ...` everywhere.

Comment: You're right – importing colors is very better than declaring variables on each file, but I think this practice is still repeating myself. Actually, I'm not afraid to have to import multiple times the colors, my problem is the digesting of the code: I don't want to see, after compiled, `$light-gray` multiple times on my css files.

Comment: And that is a real concern.  I don't know enough about your SCSS structure or how many files you have or what is defined in what, but my suggestion would be to refactor your scss so that you do not have any reference to colors in your `_boxes` file.  I think with proper refactoring, you can avoid all these redundancies.

Comment: In the example I gave, can you show me what could I refactor? It is trivial and very applicable to my real case.